# fractional ideal $I$ in number field and codifferent $C$ are related by $\operatorname{Hom}(I, \mathbb{Z}) \cong I^{-1} \otimes C $

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a number field (finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$) and $\mathcal{O}_F$ its ring of integers. Let $I$ be a fractional ideal of $F$, and let $C=\{x \in F \mid \operatorname{Tr}(xy) \in \mathbb{Z},\  \forall y \in \mathcal{O}_F \}$ be the codifferent of $F/\mathbb{Q}$. Some thing I'm reading claims we have an isomorphism (I guess of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules):
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(I, \mathbb{Z}) \cong I^{-1} \otimes C $$
via the trace pairing:

Given an element $x \otimes c \in I^{-1} \otimes C$ with $x \in I^{-1}, c \in C$, we can get a map $I \to \mathbb{Z}$ sending $i \mapsto \operatorname{Tr}(ixc)$, note that $\operatorname{Tr}(ix \cdot c) \in \mathbb{Z}$ since  $ix \in \mathcal{O}_F= II^{-1}$. This induces a map $I^{-1}\otimes C \to \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, I)$

Anyways, my question why is this an isomorphism?
(For example I'm not sure how to construct the map in the reverse direction).

Comment: Injectivity should follow from trace non-degenerate over finite separable extension by noting that $I$ is a locally free rank 1 projective module over $O_F$(i.e it contains a basis). $C$ is more or less the dual of $O_F$ homing into $Z$ in the trace sense as trace is non-degenerate. Think $y\in C$ as $Tr(y\cdot(-)):O_F\to Z$ map. Due to finite separable extension, you have integral basis, then you can construction the element of $Hom_Z(O_F,Z)$ which is multiplied by an element of $I^{-1}$ due to transformation.